# Only index.php shows up through proxy pass

Tags: php-7, localhost, apache, proxy

```
<Directory "/Users/pathto/Sites/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName developersite.dev
  ServerAlias developersite.dev
  DocumentRoot "/Users/pathto/Sites/app/"
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9070/Users/pathto/Sites/app/$1
  DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm having trouble viewing any page on my Magento 2 site outside of the main page.  Everything shows up fine on index.php(images, cms details etc).  When I go to any other page I get a message saying the requested URL was not found on server.

```
Not Found The requested URL /catalogsearch/result/ was not found on this server.
```

I'm using php70 and httpd with homebrew.  My httpd.conf has the proxy_fcgi_module uncommented, as well as rewrite_module.

My working theory is that the proxy is only handling the index.php site - not any other iterations of that. Any suggested issues with how to resolve or insights on where to look would be great.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have discovered that if I go to developersite.dev/catalogsearch/result/ I get the error as described above.  However if I go to developersite.dev/index.php/catalogsearch/result/ -- it works.  I still am not sure how to work around this problem.  web/seo/use_rewrites are set to YES.

Answer (score 1):

do not use `ProxyPassMatch` 
use `SetHandler` instead, something like this:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9070
    </FilesMatch>
<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9070">
    ProxySet connectiontimeout=7200 timeout=7200
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Good to know! Still having the same issue -- think I've made a discovery on what's going on, I'll update above.  Would love your feedback though!